# MySQL: How to Remove One Row of a Multi-Row Record Based on Column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, left-join

If I have two tables that I'm joining and I write the most simple query possible like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

There are a few records who have multiple rows per ID because they have multiple employers, so `t1` looks like this:

```
ID         Name         Employer
12345      Jerry        Comedy Cellar
12345      Jerry        NBC
12348      Elaine       Pendant Publishing
12346      George       Real Estate
12346      George       Yankees
12346      George       NBC
12347      Kramer       Kramerica Industries
```

`t2` is linked with the similar IDs but with some activities that I'd like to see -- hence the `SELECT *` above. Though I don't want multiple rows to return if the `Employer` column is "NBC" -- but everything else is good.

The only other thing that matters here is that `t2` is smaller than `t1`, because `t1` is everybody and `t2` are only from people who did particular activities -- so some of the matches won't return anything from `t2`, but I would still like them to be returned, hence the `LEFT JOIN`.

If I write the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE Employer <> "NBC"
```

Then it removes Jerry and George completely -- when really all I want is for the NBC row to not be returned, but to return any other rows that are associated with them.

How can I write the query while joining `t1` with `t2` to return each row except for the NBC ones? The ideal output would be all of the rows from `t1` regardless if they match up with all of `t2` except removing all of the rows with "NBC" as the employer in the return file. Basically the ideal here is to return the JOINs where they fit, but regardless remove the entire row for anybody with "NBC" as employer without removing their other rows.

The more I write about it, it seems like I should potentially just run a query prior to my `JOIN` to delete all the rows in `t1` who have "NBC" as their employer and then run the normal query.

Comment: So what output **do** you want for this query?

Comment: @Mureinik      Sorry for not including that -- the ideal output would be all of the rows from `t1` regardless if they match up with all of `t2` except removing all of the rows with "NBC" as the employer in the return file.

Comment: Ryan, *"The more I write about it, it seems like I should potentially just run a query prior to my JOIN to delete all the rows in t1 who have "NBC" as their employer and then run the normal query."* - **NO!! :-)) MySQL is capable of applying any logic that is ever applyable to datasets** using `SELECT` under two conditions: 1. Your data is well-formed 2. Your requirements are clear. I think you are close to a solution that works, don't give up now!

Answer (score 2):

**Basic subset filtering**

You can filter either of the two merged (joined) subsets by extending the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT    *
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON t1.ID = t2.ID
      AND t2.Employer != 'NBC'
```

If you get `null` values now, and you don't want them, you'd add:

```
WHERE t2.Employer IS NOT NULL
```

**extended logic:**

```
SELECT    *
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON (t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Employer != 'NBC')
       OR (t2.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Employer IS NULL)
```

**Using `UNION`**

Basically, `JOIN` is for horizontal linking and `UNION` does vertical linking of datasets.

It merges to resultsets: the first without NBC, and the second (which is basically an `OUTER JOIN`), adds everyone in t1 which is not part of t2.

```
SELECT    *
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON t1.ID = t2.ID
      AND t2.Employer != 'NBC'
UNION
SELECT    *
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON t1.ID = t2.ID
      AND t2.Employer IS NULL
```

---

**String manipulation in the resultset**

If you just want to remove `NBC` as a string, here is a workaround:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    IF (t2.Employer = 'NBC', NULL, t2.Employer) AS Employer
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

This basically replaces `"NBC"` by `NULL`

Comment: Thanks! This is very simple and essentially what I'm looking for. The only thing that I didn't anticipate is if I have people in `t1` and not `t2` for example, making the `LEFT JOIN` not add anything from `t2` (which is needed for my purposes), it doesn't seem to remove people with "NBC" as their employer since they don't fall into the `JOIN`. Is there any additions I can make for that to happen?

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirements and it would be best if you provide sample output in the question.

Comment: Thanks -- I added a verbal ideal output but I can get more specific if it's still too vague. Basically, it seems like yours works well whenever `t1` and `t2` have a key that matches up. But there are some people in `t1` who aren't in `t2` (which is why I did the `LEFT JOIN`) but your addition to the `LEFT JOIN` statement works well for people whose IDs match but doesn't seem to work if there's no ID match in `t2` for said person.

Comment: @Ryan I added 3 more solutions. You can extend the clause by even more logic.

Comment: Basically the ideal here is to return the JOINs where they fit, but regardless remove the entire row for anybody with "NBC" as employer without removing their other rows.